# How can I prove that $M,N,P$ are unique

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ an equilateral triangle. Let $M$ on $AC$, $N$ on $AB$ and $P$ on $BC$ s.t.$\angle CBM=x$, $\angle AMN=2x$, $\angle CNP=3x$ and $\angle PMC=90^°$. Find $x$.

It's easy to notice that $x=15$. I tried to construct phantom points and to prove that $M,N,P$ are unique with this property.

Comment: there must be a typo, what is $\angle CBP$?

Comment: @Ana  If $x=15^{\circ}$ so easy to show that $\measuredangle MNC=0^{\circ},$ which is impossible, which says $x\neq15^{\circ}.$